11S Chainring to Campagnolo Centaur Crank 135BCD
Can I use my existing Campagnolo Chainring 52/39/30 135 BCD 11spd to Campagnolo Centaur Crank 165mm? What will be the cons and pros of this? Presently, I am using the chainring with Athena 11 172.5 crank but I need to change to 165mm Centaur on the same chainring.

Both Athena and Centaur have changed quite a bit over the years. The current Centaur appears to be a 4 bolt design. Recent Athena triple use a hidden 5th bolt. So long as the rings are compatible, though, the arm length won't be a problem. Well, there's the spindle attachment too...

As long as the components fit, you will be fine. The 5-arm triple chainsets will take 5-arm rings of the same spider dimensions regardless of the number of speeds at the rear.

The hidden 5th will mean the anti-jam pin (if there is one) will be in a different place than a 5 arm plus crank configuration. Not sure about the counterbore.
